# Добавление большого количества маркеров на карту

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Здравствуйте!

Есть необходимость добавить на карту большое количество маркеров (больше 3000).  
Как я видел решение проблемы:

**1)** Разбить список на равные части, например по 300 элементов, и  для каждой части вести поиск тех, которые входят в область видимости в AsynkTask и отображать их.  Я проверил этот способ, он оказался медленным, т.к. добавление одного элемента занимает много времени, а т.к. это происходит еще и в UI потоке, то получаются тормоза.

**2)**  Добавить все элементы сразу на карту, но сделать их невидимыми, хранить список добавленных маркеров, и уже работать только над установкой видимости нужных элементов. Тут оказалась другая проблема:  момент добавления происходит также в основном потоке, поэтому даже если и показывать прогресс, то он получается рывками. И при прокрутке карты так же происходят рывки, так как работа с маркерами происходит в UI потоке.

Все действие происходит с участием Google Maps API v2.

Может у кого-то была схожая задача или есть идеи, как сделать? Поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Я вообще не понимаю, зачем показывать на экране небольшого устройства 300 маркеров. Нельзя ли как-то подгружать только те, которые находятся поблизости?

Comment: вы бы внимательно прочитали вопрос, никто не говорит об отображении 300 элементов сразу.  
Но даже и такие задачи есть.

Comment: Может быть поможет [Android. Работа с картами Google Maps. Кластеризация маркеров](http://stfalcon.com/blog/post/android-gmaps-clustering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В официальной документации есть описание того как можно рещить эту проблему. Посмотрите вот эту статью: [Too Many Markers!](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=de). В частности интересен раздел о [Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers?hl=de#fusiontables). Судя по описанию можно перенести rendering маркеров на сторону серверов Google.

Единственная проблема, версия API судя по всему третья.

**UPDATE для Android:**

- [MarkersCluster](https://github.com/Bersh/MarkersCluster)
- [Clusterkraf](https://github.com/twotoasters/clusterkraf)
- [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/)

Comment: я как бы имел ввиду карты для андроид устройств, а не web

Comment: Извиняюсь, незаметил. Тем не менее статья предлагает несколько базовых идей для реализации которые могут быть полезны.

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: окей, по сути в ответе есть правильная ссылка, но для меня кластеризация не подходит.
Однако каким-то образом библиотека Android Maps Extensions решила проблемы. в итоге я использую второй вариант действий из своего вопроса.